# Generate identity from seed table in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, identity

I need to generate an identity from a column in a seed table and increment the value in that column.

e.g

```
Seed Table:

name     "analysisid"
id       1


Analysis Table:

id
name
description
```

On the analysis mapping I need to ensure that the id is taken from the seed table and on inserting an analysis the analysisid of the seedid is updated.Do I implement a custom class inheriting from TableGenerator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate includes a number of [identity generation strategies](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator), and includes an extension mechanism for custom ones via `NHibernate.Id.IIdentifierGenerator`.

You could do this by implementing an insert trigger which fetches and assigns the next identifier for entity Analysis. In this case use `<generator class="trigger-identity" />`.

Another approach is to build your own identifier strategy by implementing `IIdentifierGenerator` and mapping as `<generator class="My.Namespace.MyIdentifierGenerator" />`.

In fluent, those generators are mapped by:

```
Id( x => x.Id ).GeneratedBy.Custom<NHibernate.Id.TriggerIdentityGenerator>();
Id( x => x.Id ).GeneratedBy.Custom<My.Namespace.MyIdentifierGenerator>();
```